# symfony2 twig - raw & slice filter together doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, themes, twig

In my twig template I have the following code:

```
<td>{{ object.content|length > 50 ? object.content|raw|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' : object.content|raw  }}</td>
```

My object `object.content` is a string like this:

```
<p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
```

I would like to output the string without the `<p>, <b>, ..` tags. That's why I add the `|raw` filter. I also only want to output **50 characters of the whole string**.

The slicing of 50 characters works but he still shows the `<p>, ..` tags.

Now when I do this:

```
<td>{{ object.content|raw  }}</td>
```

He shows the string without the `<p>` tags. But when I add the slice filter it doesn't work ... I also tried to set a variable before the output like this:

```
{% set rawcontent = object.content %}
<td>{{ rawcontent|slice(0, 50) ~ '...'  }}</td>
```

But same result... How can I fix this?

Comment: try this `{{ rawcontent | striptags | slice(0, 50)`

Comment: Works! Thanks! Could you post it as an answer? So I can approve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`striptags` should be used here instead of `raw`

```
object.content|striptags|slice(0, 50)
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/1jixsr)

Comment: Also note that if you want HTML special characters to show correctly, wrap everything around a "raw" -> (object.content|striptags|slice(0, 50))|raw

Answer (score 7):

A filter is dedicated to this kind of behavior : truncate() 
It is disabled but you can activate it :

```
services:
   twig.extension.text:
      class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
      tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
{{ entity.text|striptags|truncate(50, true, "...")|raw }}
```

The best use is when you want to limit character with HTML content.

1. You remove tags in order to note apply it with 'striptags'
2. You interprate the html entities like '&eacute' with 'raw'
3. you can count and truncate the real size of your string ;)

   ```
   {% if entity.contenu|striptags|raw|length > 50 %}
                   {{ entity.contenu|striptags|truncate(50, true, "...")|raw }}
               {% else %} 
                   {{ entity.contenu|striptags|raw }}
               {% endif %}
   ```

Or you can use it like this:

```
{{ entity.text|striptags|length > 50 ? entity.text|striptags|truncate(50, true, "...")|raw  : entity.text|striptags|raw }}
```

Hope that help...

Answer (score 3):

I tried Max Lipsky's code, then i noticed it doen't work for characters like `&atilde;` then i modified it a little and now it seems to work just fine

```
{{ event.info|striptags|length > 150 ? event.info|raw|slice(0,150)|raw : event.info|raw }}
{{ event.info|striptags|length > 150 ? '...' : ''}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried use "raw", "slice" and "~" in various combination. It doesn't working together correctly (and "striptags" too). You can use only "raw" and "slice" together.

So I found other method(looks no good, but it work):

```
{{ event.info|length > 300 ? event.info|slice(0,300)|raw : event.info|raw }}
{{ event.info|length > 300 ? '...' : ''}}
```